# How do I know if I am connected to SharePoint

Tags: 2010

I have a home computer and have seen under 'Recent documents' 'microsoft.com sharepoint' and 'internet.com.web' cal

How do I know if my computer has been connected to SharePoint? I suspect that someone using my computer is misusing it, as I have never loaded this on it.

Comment: SharePoint is a management system, not some kind of service you can connect to. So unless you have downloaded or opened something regarding SharePoint, I've got no clue.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the urls you mention, my guess is they are generic links that came with perhaps an update to office. They seem to point to non-existent websites and look to be dummy links (for instance, 'internet.com.web' is clearly a dummy link, as .com is a top level domain so it is impossible to have another extension (.web) after it...)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really tell if someone has connected to a SharePoint from your computer unless you can see it from Web Browser history, or perhaps from a firewall log. However, I don't think many home computers have firewalls that log permitted connections, only blocked connections.

SharePoint is effectively a "web site" that is accessed using web browser or dedicated software (Microsoft Office clients for example) that accesses SharePoint over the net (local or internet) so there are no programs running on your machine that would indicate that someone has connected to SharePoint at some point.